# PhpStorm doesn't show background color in .sass or .less

Tags: sass, less, phpstorm

I am really interested in showing background color in sass or less. When I put variable there it shows a background color, but when I set color to the element, the background color isn't shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment such functionality is not available if you choose to display it as a background color -- *it's available **for actual colors only** and not for variables*.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14338 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Consider also watching related tickets -- [WEB-6015](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6015) and other related to the last one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch it